# Android ScrollView smoothScrollBy not scrolling properly

Tags: android

I have some `Views` inside a vertical `ScrollView`. Sometimes the `view` that I touch is partially hidden by the ScrollView (at the bottom).

I'm using:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
v.getLocationInWindow(location);
```

With `location[1]` I can see the top Y coordinate of my view. With this and with `v.getHeight()` I can determinate if the bottom of the view is hidden in the scrollview like this:

```
scrollView.getBottom() < location[1] + v.getHeight()
```

At this point I want that the scrollView scrolls so that the view is fully visible in the scrollview (scrollView.getBottom() == location[1] + v.getHeight())

I first found the number of pixels that are hidden with;

```
int hspace = location[1] + v.getHeight() - scrollView.getBottom();
```

I've then do `scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, hspace);`. The view in fact get's fully visible but I was expecting the the bottom of the view is at the same position of the bottom of the scrollView but there is a space between them.